# is it safe to buy Lenovo T510S Laptop with SSD?

Tags: ssd, laptop

I want to buy a Lenovo laptop for a road warrior in my office who uses basically WORD/Outlook.

Config is: i5 processor, Win/7 Pro 64, 4gb RAM, dedicated graphics and 128gb SSD, Serial ATA (Intel X25-M)

Reviews are good, but some people say it's too fast and causes software problems.

Any options or experiences?

Answer (score 2):

*Too Fast?* I didn't even know that a too fast existed, you should be fine, I wouldn't be too worried about the SSD screwing anything up.